# How do I create a portable Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, display

I just moved my Raspbmc to a different monitor and the display did not come up as the new monitor supported < 1920x1080.

Is there a way to get raspxbmc to detect new monitors and scale accordingly? I am okay if this needs a reboot. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can change the resolution in the settings. Take a look in the wiki [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Settings/System)

But that's the manual way and only works when the screen works, I got mine working on a 1680x1050 screen and the Pi outputs everything correctly. Can you explain it in more detail?

Like what kind of display, what kind of HDMI cable you use (because that actually matters, at least in my experience), tested on other displays?